# StringIndexのadvanceメソッドがコンパイルエラーになる

Tags: swift, swift3

```
//Foundation フレームワークを読み込む
import Foundation

var str = "New power of String!"

// substringFromIndexは、Foundationがないと使えない
str.substringFromIndex(advance(str.startIndex, 4)) //"power of String!"になる
```

"power of String"になりません。
Advanceにエラーと表示されてしまいます。ググってみましたが、適正な回答がありません。
どうすればいいのかわかりません、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 投稿に含まれるソースコードや、整形済みのテキストは[選択した上で `{}` ボタンをクリック](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにして下さい。インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。投稿のマークアップに関しては[「Markdown または HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定する方法は?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 0):

掲示のコードは、Swift 2以前の書式に基づくものだと思われます。Swift3では、こう書きます。

```
import Foundation

var str = "New power of String!"
let newString = str.substring(from: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
print(newString)
// 出力：power of String!
```

Swift2からSwift3への移行で、関数、メソッドの書式の変化には、たとえば`substringFromIndex`というメソッド名では、`FromIndex`の部分を、引数のラベルに移そうという傾向が見られます。また、独立関数の数を減らし、メソッドに移行しようという傾向もあります。`advance`という独立関数は、String型のメソッド`index(_ i: String.Index, offsetBy n: String.IndexDistance)`に変わっています。

---

[Swift.org](https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-0-release-process/)
Swift開発者から直接発信された情報によると、今年秋頃にSwift 4がリリースされる予定になっていて、Swiftの文法の変化は、まだ終わりそうにありません。とくに`String`型について、大幅な改変が予定されていると、その情報には書かれています。それは、今回の例を見てもわかるように、文字列の5文字目から後を取り出す、1行のコードを書くのに、`str.`を3回も書かなければいけないというのは、洗練という言葉からかけ離れたものと言わなければならず、むしろどうにかしてほしい箇所です。
変化の激しい状況下では、日本語に情報を限定するのは無理があるといえます。AppleやSwift開発者からの、直接情報をあたるのが最善の手段であり、英語だからといって、敬遠している場合ではないと、考えたほうがいいでしょう。
もうひとつ、Swift2のコードをSwift3のコードに書き換えるのに、Xcode 8の、コンバート機能を活用することを、検討してください。Editメニュー＞Convert＞Edit Current Swift Syntax...で一括変換が行えます。今回のコードでは変換は成功せず、完璧とはいえませんが、8割程度の期待をしてもいいという実感があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コードってすぐに変わるんでしょうか？オンラインで著書を買ってトライしてみたのですが、やはり最新の実用書を買ってしっかり学ぶ方がいいですね。
勉強になりました。

Comment: 回答を追加しました。ご覧下さい。